# Good reference for results about separable C* algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I am studying the K-theory of C* algebras, and one result is of particular importance to me:

> The $K_0$ group of separable C* algebras is countable

I found this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3685544/1143665) that gives a good list of results about C* algebras and separability, does anyone knows a good reference for separable C* algebras? I would like to know:

- Necessary/ sufficient conditions for a c* algebra to be separable
- Properties of C* algebras

Answer (score 0):

There are very few instances where an object is called a C$^*$-algebra and it is not separable. With few exceptions, the only non-separable C$^*$-algebras that appear often in the literature are the infinite-dimensional von Neumann algebras; and these are usually treated as von Neumann algebras and not as C$^*$-algebras, for good reason: looking at these non-separable C$^*$-algebras as C$^*$-algebras is not very productive. As an example of this, $B(H)$ for infinite-dimensional separable $H$ is a non-separable, non-nuclear, non-amenable C$^*$-algebra; but as a von Neumann algebra it is separable, amenable, AFD, and as straightforward as a von Neumann algebra can be.

The zoo of separable C$^*$-algebras is so vast that it has been giving work to thousands of mathematicians for the last 80 years, and that is not about to change. The whole extremely successful *Elliott Classification Program*, that has been running for decades, is about classifying *some* separable C$^*$-algebras. Any C$^*$-algebra that is constructed out of some kind of generator set will be separable as long as the generator set is countable, which is (almost?) always the case with all C$^*$-algebras that are studied as such.

Comment: I agree that separable algebras are interesting enough on their own and that there is still so much to do here, but I think there is a lot of C* work on say, Roe algebras, which are usually not separable

Comment: Fair enough. I know nothing about Roe algebras, but there are also other classes of more or less familiar non-separable C$^*$-algebras, like injective envelopes, AW"$^*$-algebras and their cousins, continuous functions on crazy topological spaces, etc.